# SQL to ensure unique node names in adjacency list

Tags: sql, sql-server, adjacency-list

So I have an adjacency list that forms a hierarchy simulating a versioned file structure. The problem is that the incoming file names are not currently unique and they need to be. To make things *slightly* more interesting the files may have different versions which should keep the name of the first version (note the versions all have the same NodeID).

#### Adjacency List

| ParentID | NodeID | VersionNum | FileName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | 1 | 1 | FirstFolder |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | SecondFolder |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | ThirdFolder |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | FirstDocument |
| 1 | 4 | 2 | FirstDocument |
| 1 | 5 | 1 | FirstDocument |
| 1 | 5 | 2 | FirstDocument |
| 2 | 6 | 1 | FirstDocument |
| 2 | 6 | 2 | FirstDocument |
| 2 | 7 | 1 | SecondDocument |
| 3 | 8 | 1 | SecondDocument |
| 3 | 9 | 1 | ThirdDocument |
| 3 | 9 | 2 | ThirdDocument |
| 3 | 10 | 1 | ThirdDocument |
| 3 | 11 | 1 | ThirdDocument |

#### Targeted Result

| ParentID | NodeID | VersionNum | FileName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | 1 | 1 | FirstFolder |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | SecondFolder |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | ThirdFolder |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | FirstDocument |
| 1 | 4 | 2 | FirstDocument |
| 1 | 5 | 1 | FirstDocument_1 |
| 1 | 5 | 2 | FirstDocument_1 |
| 2 | 6 | 1 | FirstDocument |
| 2 | 6 | 2 | FirstDocument |
| 2 | 7 | 1 | SecondDocument |
| 3 | 8 | 1 | SecondDocument |
| 3 | 9 | 1 | ThirdDocument |
| 3 | 9 | 2 | ThirdDocument |
| 3 | 10 | 1 | ThirdDocument_1 |
| 3 | 11 | 1 | ThirdDocument_2 |

*I should also note that the folder names are already guaranteed to be unique (they already exist, it is the documents that are incoming) and they only have 1 version.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #tmp_tree
(
    ParentID INT,
    NodeID INT,
    VersionNum INT,
    FileName VARCHAR(50),
);

INSERT INTO  #tmp_tree (ParentID, NodeID, VersionNum, FileName)
VALUES (-1, 1, 1, 'FirstFolder' ),
 (1, 2, 1, 'SecondFolder' ),
 (1, 3, 1, 'ThirdFolder' ),
 (1, 4, 1, 'FirstDocument' ),
 (1, 4, 2, 'FirstDocument' ),
 (1, 5, 1, 'FirstDocument' ),
 (1, 5, 2, 'FirstDocument' ),
 (2, 6, 1, 'FirstDocument' ),
 (2, 6, 2, 'FirstDocument' ),
 (2, 7, 1, 'SecondDocument' ),
 (3, 8, 1, 'SecondDocument' ),
 (3, 9, 1, 'ThirdDocument' ),
 (3, 9, 2, 'ThirdDocument' ),
 (3, 10, 1, 'ThirdDocument' )
 (3, 11, 1, 'ThirdDocument' )
```

I really don't know how to approach this though resorting to a stored procedure. Adjacency list scream CTEs to me but that got me no where real fast. Group By loses the NodeID so while I can find the names of the documents that need to be renamed - I don't know how to use that to select the second occurrence of the name (ordered by NodeID).

```sql
-- I don't see how this helps... but this finds the names that need to change.
select ParentID, FileName,VersionNum, count(*) from #tmp_tree 
 GROUP BY ParentID, FileName, VersionNum
 HAVING VersionNum = 1 and count(*) > 1
 order by FileName
```

I know how to solve this procedural but not declaratively.

I don't know if this is closer or farther away from the solution:

```sql
 select f2.*, Row_Number() over (order by f2.FileName) from 
 (select top 10 f.*, count(FileName) over (PARTITION by ParentID, FileName) as n from (select * from #tmp_tree where versionNum = 1) as f
 order by f.ParentID, f.FileName) as f2
 Where n > 1
```

Comment: Where does the last line (3, 11) come from in the targeted result?

Comment: :) Sorry, I had meant to go back and add the node (3, 11) to the example to show a higher number of items needing to be renamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume the last line (3, 11) in the targeted result is a mistake.

You can find the repeated names with a window function in a subquery and then join it during the update. In short, you can do:

```
update #tmp_tree
set #tmp_tree.filename = concat(#tmp_tree.filename, '_', x.rn)
from #tmp_tree
join (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by parentid, filename order by nodeid) as rn
  from #tmp_tree
  where versionnum = 1
) x on x.rn > 1 and x.nodeid = #tmp_tree.nodeid;
```

Result:

```
 ParentID  NodeID  VersionNum  FileName        
 --------- ------- ----------- --------------- 
 -1        1       1           FirstFolder     
 1         2       1           SecondFolder    
 1         3       1           ThirdFolder     
 1         4       1           FirstDocument   
 1         4       2           FirstDocument   
 1         5       1           FirstDocument_2 
 1         5       2           FirstDocument_2 
 2         6       1           FirstDocument   
 2         6       2           FirstDocument   
 2         7       1           SecondDocument  
 3         8       1           SecondDocument  
 3         9       1           ThirdDocument   
 3         9       2           ThirdDocument   
 3         10      1           ThirdDocument_2
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d89c1b732221caa9a5ef95c466c8c0f1).

Comment: I was able to adapt this to my real world solution and it works like a charm. The key it would seem was understanding how `partition by` and window functions work. I could not get `row_number()` to work with `partition by` and fundamentally did not understand the error message saying it required an `order by` clause. At least I was not barking completely up the wrong tree.

Comment: Very good, but not sure why this needs a self-join

Comment: @Charlieface I'm not sure either. I guess I learned it from an old post somewhere and never looked back. Good solution +1.

Comment: Probably because all other RDBMSs don't allow this and require a self-join. I think SQL Server is the only one. It's something that a lot of people miss: updatable views, CTEs and even inline TVFs

Answer (score 2):

**You don't need to self-join the table**, you can update the derived table directly, after calculating the row-number using `DENSE_RANK`

```sql
update x
set filename = concat(x.filename, '_', x.rn)
from (
  select *,
    dense_rank() over(partition by parentid, filename order by nodeid) as rn
  from #tmp_tree
) x
where x.rn > 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ee4f7ec56f5f309337a0f186a1262284)

`DENSE_RANK` will return the same number for tied results according to the ordering clause.